# Get access to Electron API from Java and Webdriver

Tags: selenium, electron, selenium-chromedriver, minimize

I'm writing automation tests for Electron application using Java->Selenide (Selenium)->chromedriver 83.
I can successfully get access to visual elements of the app using xpath locators. But currently I need to check that window of my app is minimized after pressing "Minimize" UI button.

I can't find any easy ways to check that window is minimized from chromedriver.
May I use Electron API to get property win.isVisible or something like that? Or maybe any other ways to check that window of the Electron app is minimized?

Thanks

Comment: Have you seen this question on SQA? I think it may be relevant to you - https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/15484/how-to-minimize-the-browser-window-which-was-launched-via-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Yes, I seen this article. I don't need to minimize window. I need to understand that window is minimized or not. I have tried to get properties of window rectangle width and height, but they both are not different to corresponding sizes at normal mode. I can't find any things which may be different when window is minimized to tray.

Comment: The only way to determine that - the problem during cropping of screenshot of minimized window. In Java it takes one minute (6 attempts at 10 secs per attempt) for cropping of screenshot (with final failure).